# LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-datastore

Am testing one of my methods which is in a class in a Google App Engine Module
in android studio. am using junit.

**Problem**

when i try to run my test class, this is the error that am getting

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalRpcService: Provider com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.startServices(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:604)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.access$700(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:46)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:588)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:585)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.getService(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:584)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:500)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:479)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:456)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:533)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:530)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have googled for 2 days trying to solve this problem but all in vain

**What** should i do to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

My android project has three modlules **A**,**B** and **C**. am testing a java class that is in 
**C>src>test>java>BXC>BxcTest.java**

i have created a test folder called **BXC** where my class is located

```
//This is saved in onther class that am accessing in BxcTest.java
 @Entity
public class Presidents{
@Id Long id;
String name;
int age;

public Presidents(Long pId, String pName, int pAge){
id = pId;
name = pName
age = pAge;
}

}
```

Below is how my **BxcTest.java** looks like

```
public class BxcTest {
static{
ObjectifyService.register(Presidents.class);
}
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());


@Before
public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
}


@Test
public void methodUnderTest() throws Exception {
//my code under test
Presidents p1 = new Presidents(new Long(1),Daniel,88);
Presidents p2 = new Presidents(new Long(2),Mwai,81);
Presidents p3 = new Presidents(new Long(3),Daniel,70);
ofy().save().entities.(p1,p2,p3).now();

}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}
}
```

**UPDATE 2. ERRORS CAUSED BY**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$CompositeIndex.PARSER from class com.google.apphosting.datastore.shared.DatastoreProtoConverter
at com.google.apphosting.datastore.shared.DatastoreProtoConverter.<clinit>(DatastoreProtoConverter.java:62)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service.<clinit>(LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service.java:107)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
```

**UPDATE 3**

**This is my modlue's .gradle file**

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin   please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.14'
}
}

repositories {
jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile fileTree(dir: 'testLibs', include: ['*.jar'])
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.14'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.14'
compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.4.1'
testCompile 'org.json:json:20141113'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.21'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.21'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.21'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.21'
compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack:3.2.1'
}

appengine {
downloadSdk = true
appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
}
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
}
jvmFlags = ["-Ddatastore.backing_store=${rootDir}/data_store /local_db.bin".toString()]
}

task myCopyTask << {

copy {
    from 'src/main/assets'
    into 'build/exploded-app/assets'
}

copy {
    from '../keys'
    into 'build/exploded-app/keys'
}

copy {
    from '../cybs.properties'
    into 'build/exploded-app'
}
}

appengineRun.dependsOn myCopyTask
```

Comment: Where have you placed your testing code? 
Can you update the question with your project files structure?

Comment: @sam_dw        i have updated my question providing the folder where i have stored my test class

Comment: The structure seems good, but have you tried moving the source to C>src>functionalTest>java>package-name>ClassNameTest.java ?

Comment: Does the error log shows a "Caused by" entry? if so, please, update your post with it.

Comment: @sam_dw        i have updated my post. please have a look at it

Comment: what happens when you run your project locally, are you able to access the api explorer?,

Comment: @sam_dw        Am running it locally. what do you mean by accessing api explorer?

Comment: OK, that are two types of local run that you can do. One is solely to execute the tests and another is to run the project as it was uploaded to app engine. Once you run locally, gradle appengineRun, if the build does not fail, you can access the api explorer. To do so, launch on your browser the following: http://localhost:8080/_ah/api

Comment: @sam_dw        am running a local test on one of my classes!!!!! have you ever worked with objectify. i have updated my post so that you can see whether their is a problem with my objectify implementation. i have read objectify documentation and this is what i understand about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89813/discussion-between-gikarasojo-kinene-and-sam-dw).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's get to it!

First of all, your test is not good.
For a good sample code, please follow the following link:
[ConferenceApiGlobalQueryTest.java](https://github.com/udacity/ud859/blob/master/ConferenceCentral_Complete/src/test/java/com/google/devrel/training/conference/spi/ConferenceApiGlobalQueryTest.java)

Second, you should probably clean your gradle.build file.
Try the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.24'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.24'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.24'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.24'

    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'

    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.24'
    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.24'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If when building the compiler tells you that a package is missing, just add it back to build.gradle, and try building again. A good option for you is to just comment those packages not listed above.

Comment: Followed everything step by step, for over 5 hours but still getting the same error. i don know men what to do :(

Comment: @gikarasojokinene, push your entire app engine code (not Android) to github, and I will take a look on it.

Comment: @gikarasojokinene, were you able to push your code?

Comment: @sam-dw  am really sorry for delayment. i have created an account and now am pasting my entire code there. i will immediately give you the link.            forgive me, first time to use github :(

Comment: @sam-dw      i finally managed! i had to create another project, download the .jar files required manually, add them in my **testLibs** and **libs** directory. my test class and other classes are located in **src/main** folder. in my only **backend** folder. please have a look at the way i implemented it. https://github.com/gikarasojo/App-Engine-Module.git

Comment: @sam-dw  have you been able to look at my entire backend module?

Answer (score 1):

With great help from sam-dw, i was able to finally run my backend junit test by following the example @ [ConferenceApiGlobalQueryTest.java](https://github.com/udacity/ud859/blob/master/ConferenceCentral_Complete/src/test/java/com/google/devrel/training/conference/spi/ConferenceApiGlobalQueryTest.java).

this are the steps that i took to solve all the problems including **LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated**

- downloaded all the **.jar** files needed(**see my build.gradle file below for the needed jar files**) from [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-stubs/1.9.18)
- created **libs** and **testLibs** folder in my module(you don't have to if they already exist in your GAE module).
- Pasted the **jar** files in their corresponding folders. i.e those needed for testing i put them in **testLibs** and those needed for compilation purposes i put them in **libs** folder.
- After that, i right-clicked on my **jar** files in my folders and from the pop up menu, i choose **Add as library** and android studio added them as my module's libraries.
- All the `compile files('testLibs/xxxx.jar')` and `compile files('libs/xxxx.jar')` appeared automatically in my backend module's build.gradle file after Android studio added my jar files as libraries (so don't try to them).
- After that, i just right clicked on my test class `BxcTest` and run it. and i got the results as expected.

  **MY module's build.gradle file**

  ```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
  jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
  classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
  }
  }

   repositories {
   jcenter();
   }

   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'war'
   apply plugin: 'appengine'

   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   dependencies{
  compile files('testLibs/junit-4.12.jar')
  compile files('testLibs/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar')
  compile files('testLibs/appengine-api-stubs-1.9.18.jar')
  compile files('testLibs/appengine-api-labs-1.9.18.jar')
  compile files('testLibs/appengine-testing-1.9.18.jar')
  compile files('testLibs/appengine-tools-sdk-1.9.18.jar')
  compile files('libs/appengine-endpoints-1.9.18.jar')
  compile files('testLibs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')

  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.18'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.18'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.18'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.9.18'
  testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
  }

  appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
  oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
  getClientLibsOnBuild = true
  getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
  }
  ```

**My entity class**

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Parent;


@Entity
public class President {

@Id Long id;
@Parent Key<President> group;

@Index
String name;

int age;

static{
    ObjectifyService.register(Presidents.class);
}

 public President(Long pId, String pName, int pAge, String group){
    id = pId;
    name = pName;
    age = pAge;
    this.group = Key.create(Presidents.class,group);
 }

 public String getName(){
    return name;
 }

 public Long getId(){
    return id;

}
}
```

**My class to test.(President p3 is my current kenyan president :) )**

```
import com.example.gikarasojo.myapplication.backend.Presidents;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

public class Bxc {

 public void savingLeaders(){
    President p1 = new Presidents(new Long(1),"Daniel Moi",88,"president");
    President p2 = new Presidents(new Long(2),"Mwai Kibaki",81,"President");
    President p3 = new Presidents(new Long(3),"Uhuru Kenyatta",70,"President");
    ofy().save().entities(p1,p2,p3).now();

}
}
```

**My JUnit test(its advisable to put junit test classes in a different package. e.g creating a new package inside your main package. just right click on your package and select new>package(this is in android studio))**

```
package com.example.gikarasojo.myapplication.backend.Tests;

import com.example.gikarasojo.myapplication.backend.Presidents;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
 import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


public class BxcTest {

private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

President p1,p2,p3;

@org.junit.Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    helper.setUp();
     p1 = new President(new Long(1),"Daniel",88,"president");
     p2 = new President(new Long(2),"Mwai",81,"President");
     p3 = new President(new Long(3),"Daniel",70,"President");
    ofy().save().entities(p1,p2,p3).now();
    System.out.println("Successfully saved.");
 }

 @org.junit.After
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  ofy().clear();
    helper.tearDown();
 }

@org.junit.Test
public void testSavingLeaders() throws Exception {
 President pres1 = ofy().load().type(President.class).filter("name","Mwai").first().now();
    System.out.println("President name is: "+ pres1.getName()+ "His id is: "+pres1.getId());
 }
}
```

**THE LONG AWAITED OUTPUT!**

```
President name is: Daniel his id is: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting LocalCloudDatastoreV4Service could not be instantiated ServiceConfigurationError  in Eclipse  check your region and language settings in windows.